# Activate link on div

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, keyboard

In my HTML, i made this for have link on div.

```
<div id="up" onclick="location.href='#'"></div>
<div id="down" onclick="location.href='#'"></div>
<div id="left" onclick="location.href='#'"></div>
<div id="right" onclick="location.href='#'"></div>
```

but I'm looking for a possibility to make the links active with the keys on the keyboard. is it possible ?

Big thanks

Comment: Those are not links. You are using `div` tags with a `onclick` attribute that executes `javascript` to change the page location.

Comment: Are you trying to change the appearance of these divs when the user presses the "up", "down", "left", or "right" arrow keys on the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we listen for key press and map to click the element.

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  let elem;
  console.log(e.key);
  switch (e.key) {
    case "ArrowDown":
      elem = "down";
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      elem = "up";
      break;
    case "ArrowLeft":
      elem = "left";
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      elem = "right";
      break;
    case "Backspace":
      elem = "back";
      break;
  }

  if (elem) elem = document.querySelector(`#${elem}`);

  if (elem) {
    // Prevent event.
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    elem.innerText = "Clicked";
    elem.click();
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="up" onclick="location.href='#'"></div>
<div id="down" onclick="location.href='#'"></div>
<div id="left" onclick="location.href='#'"></div>
<div id="right" onclick="location.href='#'"></div>
<div id="back" onclick="location.href='google.fr'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect. it's totally what I needed ..

I adapted the code to my needs, I ran into one problem, the return key.

```
case "Backspace":
elem = "return";
break;

<div id="return" onclick="location.href='../page.html'"></div>
```

But it's return at the last page, same like this : *history.back()*

It's possible to use backspace for following this link ?

Big thanks

Comment: Here is a full list of keys: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values

Comment: I'm correct... it's this key that must be used : "Backspace"

i'm wrong ?

Comment: Yes, I added backspace into the demo. But as you say. You will just call `history.back();`. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history

Comment: Damned... impossible to assign a link for Backspace ?

Comment: No, I am sure you can. Try it out. You might want to cancel the keypress event though.

Comment: I use your code but i can't. For example, i come from "page1.html", i'm on "page2.html". I want to press backspace and go on "google.fr". Impossible, i return on "page1.html".

Comment: Yes i search to link backspace with the link in the div `onclick="location.href='thelink.com'"`

Comment: Take a look here, its working: https://repl.it/@PaulThomas1/TeemingBumpyProtocols

Comment: ok i know why........ firefox is incompatible :-/ . It's working on Chrome.

Comment: Gotcha. Makes sense I was testing with Chrome.

Comment: After research, mozilla use another command [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050086/firefox-keydown-backspace-issue). impossible to understand the code but it's a clue.

Comment: Impossible to work. Only way i found is replace Keyup with Keydown... and all working... but why ? Oo